# Filter out JSON array depending on content of each value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Lets say that using JSON.parse I've gotten 4 possible answers (like a multiple choice quiz) together in an array. Each value of that array has a "characteristic" (I don't know how else to call it). I want to look for a specific characteristic through each value of the array and filter out those values who do not meet the condition.

Example array:

```
0: {correct: false}
1: {correct: true}
2: {correct: false}
3: {correct: false}
```

The first value (1) of the array is the correct answer because its "characteristic" indicates it by saying it is "true". I would like to make the console to print out the number of the correct value.

Example: The correct answer is: 1

Thanks for any help

Comment: Fast note: "JSON arrays" do not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Maheer Ali said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758295/5878071), you can use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex), but it will return one value - the first one to meet the condition. In your example, if you have many objects with the `correct` key equaling `true`, you will still get one of them.

So, if you want **all** objects meeting the requirements, there are many solutions.

---

## `Array#reduce`

As suggested by [Maheer Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9819146/maheer-ali) in comments, you can try with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce).

Shorter, and with a unique loop over the array:

```js
const arr = [
     {correct: false},
     {correct: true},
     {correct: false},
     {correct: true},
  ],
  filtered = arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => ((item.correct) ? [...acc, index] : acc), []);

console.log(`the correct answers are ${filtered.join(', ')}`);
```

---

## `Array#map` and `Array#filter`

Try [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) (with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) for removing `false` values):

```js
const arr = [
     {correct: false},
     {correct: true},
     {correct: false},
     {correct: true},
  ],
  filtered = arr.map((item, index) => ((item.correct) ? index : false)).filter((item) => (item));

console.log(`the correct answers are ${filtered.join(', ')}`);
```

However, the array will be looped through two times (one time by `Array#map`, and an other time by `Array#filter`.

---

## `for...in` statement

Eventually, you could do this by pushing the indexes in an empty array by iterating the original one with a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in) loop:

```js
const arr = [
     {correct: false},
     {correct: true},
     {correct: false},
     {correct: true},
  ],
  filtered = [];
  
for (let index in arr) {
  if (arr[index].correct) {
    filtered.push(index);
  }
}

console.log(`the correct answers are ${filtered.join(', ')}`);
```

---

Comment: I deleted the old comment.How about `reduce()` single loop `arr.reduce((ac,a,i) => a.correct ? [...ac,i] : ac,[])`

Comment: Nice (and better) suggestion. I added it to my answer. ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which returns the index of the first element of array which matches the condition.

```js
const arr = [
   {correct: false},
   {correct: true},
   {correct: false},
   {correct: false},
]

console.log(`the correct answer is` + arr.findIndex(x => x.correct))
```